# MYSQL Update a table from fresh external source

Tags: mysql, updates

I have a table rates, of telephony costs by prefix. say columns are
id, provider, prefix, buyrate

Monthly, I get a update from a provider, of their new rates. Some prefixes will be new, some will be missing (and thus need deleting from rate), some will be just updates. Assume updates are in identical table structure newrate.

I have multiple providers, so only a portion of rate table will be changing, and I would *like* to keep existing rate.id for updates where possible. So, what queries would I need to run to do the following:

1) update prices for any matching prefixes for provider x, keeping rate.id
2) delete any rate entries for prefix dropped by provider x
3) insert any new prices for new prefixes

Example
Original rate

```
id, provider, prefix, buyrate
1   1         0044    10
2   2         0044    11
3   2         0067    9
4   2         0072    13
5   3         0084    17  
Updates from provider 2
1   2         0067    8
1   2         0069    12
1   2         0072    16
New rate
1   1         0044    10
3   2         0067    8
4   2         0072    16
5   3         0084    17
6   2         0069    12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE table1 dest, (SELECT * FROM table2 where provider=2) src 
SET dest.provider = src.provider where dest.provider=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how complicated a solution you are looking for. In its simplest form, something like the following:

For updates:

```
update rates set buyrate=<new rate> where provider=x and prefix=y
```

For deleting:

```
delete from rates where provider=x and prefix=y
```

For new prices:

```
insert into rates values (<id>, <provider>, <prefix>, <buyrate>
```

Also there are some performance considerations, and the size of your table (original, and update file) - you could do a query for each entry for existing data to determine which entries are updates, what rows are missing, and which are new. You could batch this up (eg compare 1000 at a time, and split into three lists, one for updates, one for inserts, and one for deletes)

Comment: Not sure about the insert - what about already existing items? i.e. the ones you have just updated with first query ? And your queries don'e seem to reference the new rate table newrate